# Merge two tables with multiple join conditions in Power Query

Tags: sql, join, merge, powerbi, powerquery

I have 2 tables as below (**Table1** and **Table2**). I have to join these 2 tables with multiple joining criteria in Power Query:

1. Join on Transaction_ID from both the tables and
2. Also, join on Table1.Transaction_Dt should be between Table2.Sale_From_Dt and Table2.Sale_To_Dt.

However, I'm able to do it in SQL (mentioned below). But then not able to do it using **Power Query**.

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.Transaction_ID = B.Transaction_ID
     AND A.Transaction_Dt>=B.Sale_From_Dt AND A.Transaction_Dt<=B.Sale_To_Dt
```

**Table1**

| Transaction_ID | Item_Name | Transaction_Dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Pen | 21-May-2022 |
| 1002 | Laptop | 6-Aug-2022 |
| 1003 | Phone | 1-Nov-2022 |
| 1004 | Case | 25-Apr-2022 |
| 1005 | Wire | 19-Aug-2022 |
| 1006 | Cake | 15-Mar-2022 |
| 1007 | Ice cream | 16-Mar-2022 |
| 1008 | Book | 5-Nov-2022 |

**Table2**

| Transaction_ID | Amount | Sale_From_Dt | Sale_To_Dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1005 | 500 | 1-Aug-2022 | 30-Aug-2022 |
| 1008 | 120 | 1-Oct-2022 | 30-Oct-2022 |
| 1007 | 345 | 1-Mar-2022 | 30-Mar-2022 |
| 1009 | 643 | 1-Feb-2022 | 28-Feb-2022 |
| 1002 | 900 | 1-Oct-2022 | 30-Oct-2022 |
| 1004 | 3498 | 1-Apr-2022 | 30-Apr-2022 |
| 1001 | 34 | 1-Mar-2022 | 30-Mar-2022 |
| 1003 | 456 | 1-Nov-2022 | 30-Nov-2022 |
| 1005 | 345 | 1-Jul-2022 | 30-Jul-2022 |
| 1008 | 345 | 1-Nov-2022 | 30-Nov-2022 |
| 1007 | 908 | 1-May-2022 | 30-Ma7-2022 |
| 1009 | 125 | 1-Jan-2022 | 28-Jan-2022 |
| 1002 | 3787 | 1-Aug-2022 | 30-Aug-2022 |
| 1004 | 987 | 1-Dec-2022 | 30-Dec-2022 |
| 1001 | 7634 | 1-May-2022 | 30-May-2022 |
| 1003 | 760 | 1-Nov-2022 | 30-Nov-2022 |

Can someone please help me with the same?

Thanks!!

Comment: You know that you can import using SQL? Just asking because many people don't know.

Comment: @FernandoBarbosa - My source is Azure Analysis Services

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do pull the matching rows Table2:

Add column, custom column with formula

```
(i)=>(Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [Transaction_ID]=i[Transaction_ID] and i[Transaction_Dt]>=[Sale_From_Dt] and i[Transaction_Dt]<=[Sale_To_Dt]))
```

If you want to get at the Amount field for the match, you can use this instead:

```
(i)=>(Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [Transaction_ID]=i[Transaction_ID] and i[Transaction_Dt]>=[Sale_From_Dt] and i[Transaction_Dt]<=[Sale_To_Dt] ) [Amount]{0})
```

I'd suggest you buffer Table2 first, if the data is large, as in sample code below:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Transaction_ID", Int64.Type}, {"Item_Name", type text}, {"Transaction_Dt", type date}}),
Table2Buffer=Table.Buffer(Table2),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom",  (i)=>(Table.SelectRows(Table2Buffer, each [Transaction_ID]=i[Transaction_ID] and i[Transaction_Dt]>=[Sale_From_Dt] and i[Transaction_Dt]<=[Sale_To_Dt] ) [Amount]{0}),type number)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Sorry @horseyride - I didn't get what you are trying to explain. To create a custom column in Table1 referring columns from Table2, we need to join these 2 tables first right. I'm struggling with joining these 2 tables with the required conditions applied.

Please correct me if I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: There is no merge operation that does what you want. This code creates a column in Table1 that pulls matching IDs with appropriate date ranges from Table2. You can do with that table whatever you want. I was drilling into it to pull the Amount. I don't know how else to explain it